# E-Mail tool for Transactional, Automated and Newsletter E-Mails

Tags: email, mailchimp, newsletter, transactional

I’m looking for a E-Mail tool to fit my needs. Right now we use Mandrill for transactional E-Mails and Mailchimp for Newsletters. We would love to cover the Automated E-Mails also with Mailchimp, but the tools are quite limited (see our requirements in 2.).
My gut feeling says, there is no [single] tool to cover my needs, but before I spend months developing a stable tool which handles all of my needs, I thought I would reach out to you.

Here are my needs:

1. Transactional E-Mails:
   We want to use it to send transactional emails. Depending on [the category of] what the customer bought, the context of the email will be different (e.g. other images, texts). There will be up to 20 different categories.
2. Automated E-Mails:
   We want to send an E-Mail to a customer for his birthday or before an ordered product arrives. As our products usually take between 1 month and 1 year to deliver, we also want to send an E-Mail, enriched with detailed information about the product, 1 month and also 1 day in prior. Now the important part: Some customers have up to 3 outstanding deliveries per year.
   In a perfect world, all this timings and the templates can be edited by our marketing personnel, not just by a developer.
3. Newsletter E-Mails:
   Each customer and/or customer group should become a personalised  newsletter. Therefor the newsletter tool has to be fed with data about the customer from our systems/Salesforce.
4. All customer specific data is in Salesforce. Therefor the ideal mail system has a good Salesforce integration.

Do you know of any product[s] like this? What would you use?
Thank you!

Comment: You may want to post this over on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

At Stack Overflow, our needs are similar. We send a bunch of triggered transactional emails, automated "drip" emails, and digest newsletters. Until recently, we sent everything through our own codebase using homegrown tools, but **we're in the process of transitioning over to [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)**. We also looked at [Mail Gun](http://www.mailgun.com/) and [Send With Us](https://www.sendwithus.com/), but SendGrid seemed like the best fit and we hope to send everything through one ESP.

We don't use Salesforce, so I can't comment on that.